# Sympy - comparing equivalent expressions with equal (=) sign

Tags: python, sympy

I understand that in Sympy, the == equivalence does not work for symbolic expressions and hence cannot be used to check for symbolic equivalence. From the documentations, it is recommended to use `simplify (a-b)` and check if the result is 0. E.g.,

```
>>> simplify((x + 1)**2 - (x**2 + 2*x + 1))
```

However, this does not seem to work for expressions with equals in them. E.g., I want to compare (2x=6 and x=3), which should be equal.

```
>>> a = Eq(2*x,6)
>>> b = Eq(x,3)
>>> simplify(a-b)
−x=3+(2x=6)
```

Or more complex equations which should be equivalent

```
>>> a = Eq(x*(y+1),6)
>>> b = Eq(2*x*y + 2*x, 12)
>>> simplify(a-b)
(x(y+1)=6)−(2x(y+1)=12)
```

Wondering if there is a good way or trick to do this in Sympy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes these equations equivalent is that they have the same solution set or that they are the same when solved for `x`. Have sympy solve them and compare the solutions:

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')

a = Eq(2*x,6)
b = Eq(x,3)
print(solve(a) == solve(b)) #True
```

The same works for your more complex example:

```
a = Eq(x*(y+1),6)
b = Eq(2*x*y + 2*x, 12)
print(solve(a)) # [{x: 6/(y + 1)}]
print(solve(b)) # [{x: 6/(y + 1)}]
print(solve(a) == solve(b)) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Each expression has two useful methods `equals()` and `compare()`:

```
x,y = symbols('x,y')
a = (9*x+30*x+21) / 3
b = x*(3+10)+7
a.equals(b)
```

Output:

```
True
```